# How to merge two classes in separate files into one ES6 module using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have two files and every file I have a class:

```
//Hello.ts
export class Hello {
    private n: number = 100;
    private s: string = "Hi";
    public prints(s: string): void {
    console.log(s);
    }
}
//Foo.ts
import {Hello} from 'Hello'
export class Foo {
    public test(): void {
        let hello: Hello = new Hello();
    hello.prints("Hi");
    }
}
```

When I do `tsc Hello.ts Foo.ts --target es6 --out module.js` I get `Cannot compile modules using option 'out' unless the '--module' flag is 'amd' or 'system'.` How to merge two classes in separate files into one ES6 module?

I opened issue asking to [implement such feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27426), but I was said that it is supported already.

Comment: @AluanHaddad It is very clear - I want to develop every class in separate file as it is a standard and convenient way to develop classes. From other side I want to use es6 modules as they give a lot of advantages.

Comment: @Pavel_K I see. Run `tsc Hello.ts Foo.ts --target es6 --module es6 --outdir dist`. `--module` and `--target` are independent.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I tried what you suggested. In folder `dist` I get two files `Hello.js` and `Foo.js` but I need only one file that is module.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Because these two classes must be in one module and I put them in separate files only for convenience.

Comment: To combine files, `--module` has to be set to either `system` or `amd` which aren't ES6.

Comment: @Adam quite, but those do not produce a single module, they produce a bundle. That is fine but it isn't what is requested.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I understand that. I'm pointing out that setting the `--module` argument is the only way to combine files.

Comment: @Adam indeed. I just have a feeling this is a chicken and egg problem. It's easy to misunderstand these concepts since module is such an overloaded term and since some tools use it to specify input, some output, and some either or both.

Comment: Which things do you expect the bundled ES6 module to export?

Comment: Even if typescript is not capable of doing this, [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en) should be.

Comment: @Bergi I think final module exports/imports must be configured on the information in my classes.

Comment: @Pavel_K What do you mean by "*on the information in my classes*"? The final module is usually configured by writing a module that looks like `export { Hello } from '/hello'; export { Foo } from '/foo';`.

Comment: @Bergi Ok, then It can be done this way - I create module.ts and explicitly set exports/imports of the module and the classes that must be included.

Comment: @Bergi I asked this question as I opened issue, but I was said that such feature is already supported https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27426

Comment: @Pavel_K Maybe they didn't understand that you want an ES6 module as output

Comment: @Pavel_K To reduce the amount of "configuration" you have to hard-code in the final module, you could consider `export * from '/hello'; export * from '/foo';` .  The TypeScript compiler will give you an error if there are any name conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

## Re-exporting members

You can make the classes `Foo` and `Hello` accessible from a single module:

```
// main.ts
export { Hello } from "./Hello";
export { Foo } from "./Foo";
```

Now these classes are available from 2 modules: their original file, and `main`.

## Using Rollup

Additionally, like Bergi suggests in a comment, you can use Rollup with a plugin for TypeScript: [this one](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-typescript) or [this other](https://github.com/ezolenko/rollup-plugin-typescript2).

Rollup takes several modules and produce one module with just the exports of the entry point module. You can test online [with the REPL](https://rollupjs.org/repl?version=0.66.2&shareable=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) (using JavaScript syntax because the REPL hasn't the plugin for TypeScript).